# Item spacing within ItemsControl Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am generating buttons on the fly. The `List<Button>` is bound to the an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons}" Padding="0" 
    Style="{StaticResource HorizontalStackPanel}" />
```

Here is the style definition:

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

A button is generated using the following method:

```
private Button MakeAButton(string letter)
{
    Button b = new Button
    {
        Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(-2),
        CommandParameter = letter
    };

    b.Content = new TextBlock { Text = letter, FontSize = 24, FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Segoe UI Mono") };
    b.Click += b_Click;
    return b;
}
```

The number of buttons varies every time. I need them to be all visible on the phone page and be spread apart such that the user has an easy time pushing the buttons.

Problem: Buttons are spread out inside ItemsControl in such a way so that if there are more than 8 buttons in the collection, they start disappearing from the screen. Controlling the space by setting the Margin on buttons works, but then I have to adjust it for every number of items in the collection. Setting MaxWidth on the ItemsControl does not work. I measured my buttons individually and the sum of all `.DesiredSize` does not exceed 250px.

Questions: Is there a way to programmatically control the space between items within ItemsControl? More importantly, what mechanism does ItemsControl use to space items within it?

Comment: A grid with a fixed height would give the desired behavior, but I'm not sure how to use it with a data source

Comment: @KooKiz Can I use any other controls instead of ItemsControl? I need to lay my buttons in rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [WrapPanel](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs) instead of a [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). A WrapPanel allows the content to wrap around the screen and not go off the screen. You can use the WrapPanel within the Windows Phone Toolkit or Telerik's controls or any other third party WrapPanel.

If using the WP Toolkit, modify you style to be as such

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That actually made it worse. With a StackPanel as a template, whatever overflow there was stayed on one row. The same buttons in WrapPanel take two rows and the screen estate on the phone is quite limited. +1 for the suggestion though.

Comment: The only way to fit the items (without using a ScrollViewer) is to shrink them every time another is added, or use a WrapPanel. I don't think you want to shrink them every time as you'll end up with tiny buttons.

Comment: Do you know how ItemsControl spaces its children?

Comment: The ItemsControl does not specify any spacing. That is defined in the ItemTemplate. In your template, you define how they should be spaces.

Comment: So why does the size of all my items not add up to the width of the page then? I measure each Button and TextBlock by calling the Control.Measure(Size) method and then add up DesiredSize property and its way less than the available width size.

Comment: Can you post your DataTemplate?

Comment: I actually don't have one (see the first code fragment). MyButtons property is a List<Button>.